# Commenting (out) code in Angular2 TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, comments

I have the following Angular2 TypeScript code with a section commented out as per Javascript convention:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
    `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{lene.name}}</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{lene.id}}</div>
    /*<div>
       <label>name: </label>
       <input [(ngModel)]="lene.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>*/`
    <div><label>description: </label>{{lene.description}}</div>
})
```

However, once the TypeScript compiles to Javascript I get the following output to my web browser:

[image: Browser image]

I've searched the API docs and can't find an entry specifying the syntax for this quite basic feature. Anyone know how you do multi-line comments in TypeScript?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`/* */` is typescript comment delimiter

They don't work inside a string literal.

You can use HTML comment syntax instead `<!-- -->`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
    `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{lene.name}}</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{lene.id}}</div>
    <!-- <div>
       <label>name: </label>
       <input [(ngModel)]="lene.name" placeholder="name">
    </div> -->'
    <div><label>description: </label>{{lene.description}}</div>
})
```

The HTML commented out this way still is added to the DOM but only as comment.

Comment: Basically, because the template section is parsed as HTML not Javascript, I should be using HTML syntax for the comments, right? Or is it more complex than that? Either way the solution works :).

Comment: From the TypeScript point-of-view `\`<h1 ... /div>\`` is a string. Within strings comments (actually almost everything except string interpolation) is ignored. When using HTML comment syntax the string is fowarded to the browser (including the `<!-- -->`) which then interprets this part of the string as comment.

Comment: Interesting info about the comment delimiting. Do you know of an example or an API doc reference so I could look it over?

Comment: TypeScript comment syntax is basically [ES5 comment syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4) with some additions like "Source File Dependencies" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072286/where-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-comments-documented. Backticks are explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm working on a very simple Angular2 project and have an HTML comment in my template and the comment is not being added to the DOM. The code runs, but no comment in the output.

Comment: It's likely that Angular just strips comments. What's the point of adding them anyway. You could try `<div [innerHTML]="<!-- my comment -->"></div>`. You might require what is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The point of adding comments? Documentation? Anyway, I wanted to ask because your answer indicated that normal HTML comments would be added to the DOM (and you would think that they would), but I'm not seeing that behavior.

Comment: In the source code the comments stay available, but for the browser it's considered more important to reduce file size as much as possible.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Not sure about that. Angular is outputting its own HTML comments to the DOM, just not mine. And, there are certainly use cases where documentation in the response is warranted.

Comment: "outputting its own HTML comments to the DOM" I think you mean what Angular adds as placeholder for binding for example with `*ngFor`. This doesn't add to download size because it's added dynamically through code. Have you tried above workaround?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Your suggestion causes a "Template parse error". This is an Angular2 application, BTW.

Comment: That same code causes a "Template parse error" in my app. I'll play with this more. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the template, use the HTML comment `<!-- ... -->`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{lene.name}}</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{lene.id}}</div>
    <!-- div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="lene.name" placeholder="name">
    </div-->
    <div><label>description: </label>{{lene.description}}</div>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem to work, though, because it only hides the HTML, while still trying to execute the typescript code inside the commented section.